# In SP 2013, why is there a Checked Out To column

Tags: 2013, document-library, check-out

Why is there a `Checked Out To` column when only the users who have files checked out can see them?

Sure, it saves you squinting for the checked out mark on the document icon, but surely there must be a way to see other users' files without going to Library Settings.

Comment: What exactly you would want to achieve? Can you elaborate your question a little more please.

Comment: Actually not only the user can see the file. The column tell you who is working on the file

Comment: OK - in Sharepoint 2013 / Office 365, if a user adds a document to a library with mandatory columns, without populating the data or checking it in, my understanding (and experience) show that the original user can then see the document in the view, but other users cannot, unless they are Site Admins who can go to the 'Manage files which have no checked in version.' link in Site Settings. If there is a way to set things up so that all users can see the files (with the 'Checked Out' icon) then please inform me how. Thanks, Vaughan

Comment: That is how the environment works, there is nothing that I know of that can change that behavior unless you write server side code to surface it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version settings you have, the usefulness of the column differs. It isn't as useful when there are documents that have not been published as major versions, anything less than 1.0. After the files are major versions where the files are visible to all, it becomes beneficial as everyone can see who has the file locked for editing.

Comment: Thanks, but versioning is not turned on for the library in question, but mandatory Check Out/In is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, by a lot of trial and error I have discovered that other users' checked out files only become visible once they have been checked in for the first time, and then checked out again. This must relate to the document not being considered a 'major version' until it's been checked in once.
Thanks again, all, for your help.